# How can I run delayed logic with rxjs after receiving a value from a subscription?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, delay, rxjs6

i want to run part of my logic after my subscription with an additional delay (with RxJS). I know about the finalize operator, which i could use with a pipe, but that would lead to an immediate execution after the completion of my observable.

Is there a way to create a delay before running finalize?

Additional information:

I am subscribing to a server call, meaning i am only expecting one value.

Comment: Have you tried `concat(main$, timer(N).pipe(finalize(() => {...})))` ?

Comment: So you want to emit the result immediately, but then wait a specified amount of time before the observable completes, even though you only ever expect a single emission?  May I ask what is the use case is for such a behavior?

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to create a delay before the `finalize`.

You can subscribe to a [`timer`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/timer) in [`finalize`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/finalize).

This is not an anti-pattern and is a safe operation. `finalize` is called only **once**, after the source observable has been **emitted** and **completed**.

Look at this example:

```js
of([1,2,3])
.pipe(
    finalize(() => {
        timer(1000).subscribe(() => {/* 1s delayed execution */})
    })
)
.subscribe(value => {
    console.log(value);
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use the delay operator within a pipe.
`Observable.pipe(deplay(200))...`

Resources: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/delay

Comment: this would also delay the actual value emission. I want the delay to happen after the emission of the value.